# Child element of body not taking 100% space when body has min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

The following code [works properly](http://rushbase.net/~rush/test2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Working</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%; /* !!!!! difference in here */
}
div#main {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

while a code using `min-height` instead of `height` for body [prevents #main from occupying space](http://rushbase.net/~rush/test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Not working</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%; /* !!!!! difference in here */
}
div#main {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

Weird thing is when doing an inspect in chrome, in both cases body properly takes up 100% space. In `min-height` case however the child element `min-height: 100%;` translates to 0. Why does it happen and is there any workaround? I would like the min-height for my web page for background to work properly and expand as needed.

Comment: Are you overlaying backgrounds of `body` and `#main`? Is that why you need both to expand with content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### As to "Why does it happen?"

The `min-height` property only works if an explicit height is set. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights) reads for a percentage:

> Specifies a percentage for determining the used value. The percentage
>   is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this
>   element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated
>   as '0' (for 'min-height') or 'none' (for 'max-height').

The key point in that is that "If the height of the containing block is not
specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height)." When `body` is set with `min-height`, it is *still depending on content height* for calculation, only it does not allow it to fall below the specified size (in your case, 100% of `html` height which is explicitly set). However, because `body` is still depending on content to set its height, then `div#main` cannot calculate `min-height` because `body` does not have an explicit height set.

### Is a "Workaround" Needed?

It seems that setting `body` to `height: 100%` achieves all you want. Whether [content is long](http://jsfiddle.net/TN3LD/8/) or [content is short](http://jsfiddle.net/TN3LD/7/).

### Response to Comment on `html` change of `background-color`

I suspect the reason [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eevq6/) with `html` having `background-color` set changes things is because of the notations in [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background) (quoted below). By setting that on `html` it changes the *[canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#the-canvas)* rendering itself:

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
>   canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for
>   'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was
>   painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not
>   paint this background again.
>
> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. For
>   documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element. Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the
>   same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root
>   element.

Comment: Thanks, certainly answers that part of my question. The workaround part is still needed. ... or maybe I just need a different layout.

Comment: @RushPL--see my addition (and fiddle links with it). I think setting explicit height on body to 100% does what you would need.

Comment: I was a bit amazed of your solution having worked as I would swear I tried something similiar without success. I tracked the problem down to `html { background-color: #111111; }` which I illustrate over here http://jsfiddle.net/eevq6/ Thanks a lot for helping out! Still a bit weird behaviour of background-color in the html element. You can uncomment `background-color` from `html` to see proper behaviour.

Comment: @RushPL--added to my answer what I think is the explanation as to why setting the `background-color` on `html` created "weird behaviour."

Comment: This is awkwardly limiting, since height 100% on the html element required for body min-height does not expand over the whole page when the content overflows.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting an `&nbsp;` inside the `<div id="main"/>` tag.

Comment: you obviously didn't try this yourself.